# Query hash/range key and local secondary index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Is it possible to Query a DynamoDB table using both the hash & range key AND a local secondary index?

I have three attributes I want to compare against in my query. Two are the main hash and range keys and the third is the range key of the local secondary index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but that shouldn't be necessary based on your description of what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are trying to access an object based on the hash and range key (of the main table) as well as an additional attribute, selecting on only the hash and range of the main table (which is required to return a single record by definition) will return that record.

If your concern is that the third attribute may be a value that you want to ignore the entire record you can use a query filter to have that item filtered out by DynamoDB or you can use logic in your application to ignore that object.

Comment: +1 for clarifying "selecting on only the hash and range of the main table (which is required to return a single record by definition) will return that record"